# Upload image from sd-card on tumbler in Android

Tags: android, post, request, tumblr, photo

I have uploaded image using a http://... URL. but i dont want to use URL .I want to upload image on tumbler from local sdcard of mobile.
I tried all these solutions [Uploading Images to tumblr API from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845208/uploading-images-to-tumblr-api-from-android) but nothing worked for me.

i posted image by URL like this :-

```
File fil = savebitmap(pattern_a);
        HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"
                + strBlogName.replace(" ", "%20") + ".tumblr.com/post");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "photo"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", "hello"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source","http://pchtanks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/tropical-fish11.jpg"));
```

**UPDATE**

I am using this code

```
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "photos"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("set_total", "1"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Akanksha"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", "Hello yar"));

             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("original","0"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", fil.getAbsolutePath().toString()));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", encodedImage));
//              localContentValues2.put("tumblr_post_id", Long.valueOf(paramLong));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("width", String.valueOf(pattern_a.getWidth())));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("height", String.valueOf(pattern_a.getHeight())));
                localArrayList.add(nameValuePairs);

hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));



    consumerconsumer.sign(hpost);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse resp = null;
    resp = client.execute(hpost);

    result = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
    PrintLog.LOGV("Result : " + result);
```

I got the encodedImage like this :-

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    pattern_a.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); 
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray(); 
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I am getting Error : - **Bed request, Post can not be empty.**

I think i am missing something in parameter or i am sending any wrong tag.

Do any body have any solution.
I have downloaded jumblr jar file. but i don't know how to use it. Is my work is possible without jumbler. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

The source does not expect URL. It expects URI. Did you try :`nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source","file:///sdcard/img.png"));` ?

Moreover, instead of source, you can specify `data` and supply the actual bytes of the image using a bytebuffer